# nginx configuration targeting a folder like htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, configuration

I'm moving from Apache to nginx, have many .htaccess files throughout the site (e.g. example.com/.htaccess, example.com/folder/.htaccess).

An example of a .htaccess file I have is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^do_ajax\.php /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And the nginx conf equivalent is something like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
rewrite ^/ajax /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php last;
# END WordPress
```

Since the nginx configuration goes in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and targets all files instead of the folder, is there anything I can do to make it target the particular folder it's meant for (e.g. if the above folder for www.example.com is located at /usr/share/nginx/html/example/)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the "folder" part in the match:

```
rewrite ^/folder/ajax /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php last;
```

since these nginx rules are not *per directory* context. But if you need to group them together you could use the [`location` block](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location):

```
location /folder/ {
   rewrite ^/folder/ajax /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php last;
}
```

if you want to group them together, but you *still* need the `/folder/` in front of the regex.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What if I have it set up as folder.example.com, where the folder is located at /usr/share/nginx/html/example/? I'll be having other folders set up like folder2.example.com (/example2/) and so on.